# Stuck On A Method/Class Reference Issue (JAVA Basic)

Tags: java, function, class, methods, reference

My aim was to create a little bit of code which allows my computer to randomly select how it refers to me. "Hello " + (randomly selected nickname) + ", how are you today?"

Pretty simple, right? Not to a noob like me!

**Referenced Class**
I gave it 4 choices of names, and it selects one at random and prints it out.

```
public class NameRef {

     public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<String> nickNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        nickNames.add("DJ");
        nickNames.add("Buddy");
        nickNames.add("Dude");
        nickNames.add("Sir");

        Random rand = new Random(); 
        rand.nextInt(4);

        System.out.println(nickNames.get(rand.nextInt(4)));
    }
}
```

**Main Class**
I wanted this class to take the information from that secondary class' function and reference to it in my greeting.

```
public class CodeTesting extends NameRef {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + /*The product from the NameRef*/  + " how are you?");
    }
}
```

I don't know how I am supposed to reference that information? I've tried is a hundred ways!

I also tried to make a function in the secondary class that RETURNED a name string but then I wasn't able to reference that in my main class...

I am so confused. Any help as to where I'm going wrong would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `main` in `NameRef` to a function that returns `String`. So instead of `System.out.println(nickNames.get(rand.nextInt(4)));`, it should instead do `return nickNames.get(rand.nextInt(4))`. Then in `CodeTesting` class, call the function like this:

```
public class CodeTesting extends NameRef {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + nameOfFunction()  + " how are you?");
    }
}
```

Where `nameOfFunction` is the name you call the function you created

Comment: Thanks so much! 

This has been bugging me all night! 

awesome sauce! ty

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NameRef {

     public String getName(){

        ArrayList<String> nickNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        nickNames.add("DJ");
        nickNames.add("Buddy");
        nickNames.add("Dude");
        nickNames.add("Sir");

        Random rand = new Random(); 
        rand.nextInt(4);

        return nickNames.get(rand.nextInt(4));
    }
}

public class CodeTesting extends NameRef {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       NameRef nameRefObject = new NameRef();
        System.out.println("Hello, " +nameRefObject.getName()+ " how are you?");
    }
}
```